# How to make checkbox as button with confirm message?

Tags: javascript, python, django, checkbox, django-templates

I'm Junior Django dev. It's my first project in my company and I have a FrontEnd task.

The frontend is black magic for me but trying my best but here I am totally lost;/

**Task to do:**

> "If I click on checkbox it redirect to page with an endpoint which change
>   value of checkbox from on to off"

I wrote all backend staff... and even some kind of frontend but it is not working as I want it to. I've tried loads of combination but I still don't know.

**Code of checkbox:**

```
<table>
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody>
        <td>
            <a href="{% url 'product_user_paid_change' tp_id=item.pk paid=item.paid %}" onclick="return confirm('For surechange - {{ item.full_name }}?')">
                <div class="checkbox m-15">
                    <label for="id_paid"><input type="checkbox"{% if item.paid == True %} checked{% endif %} ><i class="input-helper"></i></label>
                </div>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

> **And what is happening here?**
>
> 1. When I click directly on checkbox there appears a confirmbox when I
>      click "OK", checkbox change state but request is not send...
> 2. When I click outside checkbox there is confirmbox and when I click "OK" I'm correctly redirected to request site.

How to make it work when I click directly on checkbox... not only outside? ;/

I tried to transport this  before div, after div, before label, inside label... nothing works.

I will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its pretty simple, and as my edit dont have nothing to do with python or django.

What you have to do it create one input checkbox at your template

```
<input type="checkbox" id="my_awesome_checkbox">
```

Create one javascript function or just bind the code to event in that input

```
<input type="checkbox" id="my_awesome_checkbox" onchange="myCuteFunction">

function myCuteFunction() {    
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("my_awesome_checkbox")

  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    let result = confirm("Hey! You really want to leave me here?");
    if (result){
        location.replace("the url you wan to go");
    }

  }
}
```

**EDIT**: You want to changed the Checkbox value based on information from your backend?

If is that you can use ajax to get the response you want from your endpoint and change your checkbox

So using the previous code you can call the ajax to reach your backend instead of changing the page your url... and than change the value of your checkbox

```
function myCuteFunction() {    
      var checkBox = document.getElementById("my_awesome_checkbox")

      if (checkBox.checked == true){
        let result = confirm("Hey! You really want to leave me here?");
        if (result){
            $.ajax({
                url: "<your endpoint>",
                  context: <necessary paramenters>
                }).done(function() {
                  <your response to add your logic to change the checkbox>
                });
        }

      }
    }
```

Comment: I should mention this... I'm creating the rows in {% for ... %}, so <a href=....> are generated automatically. For first row and first checkbox ".../product/1/1/", for second ".../product/1/2/", for third ".../product/1/3/", etc. so checkbox name is shared.... and every row only <a href=...> changes.
I thought I gave enough information... seems I was wrong ;/

Comment: Maybe something like this? In checkbox "onclick" i'm passing the necessary variables through function? and then myCuteFunction automatically generates url? but inside function? Or should i pass full url?

Comment: Depends... you need to change the checkbox based in someone from your Django? or you just need some url based in some logic in frontend?